# Is the Facebook JavaScript API suitable to create user accounts?

Tags: javascript, facebook

I want users to be able to register on my mobile (web based) app and login using their Facebook account. Is this possible using the JavaScript API?

The user can login using Facebook, and the userID and auth code of that user can be sent to my server to create the account, but I see a security flaw because then anyone could then log in as anyone by sending a userID and their own auth code. So can user accounts not be done with the JavaScript API and only with a server side API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Facebook requests are also signed with a secret key that belongs to the app you've registered to handle Facebook sign-ups on your website, so you can use that to verify it comes from Facebook and not someone else.

This is also outlined in the [registration documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/)

Comment: Ok so is this the flow: User clicks register in my app, they authorised my app and login to facebook, the data is sent back to my JavaScript function signed using my secret key, I sent this data to my server (running in python) which checks the signature using my secret key to make sure it is correct, then I create the facebook linked account on my system? What is to stop someone from logging in to facebook and then intercepting and changing the username or userID on the client side before it is sent to my server?

Comment: It's a signed request. You recalculate the signature and compare it to Facebook's calculated one. If they are different, someone changed the data. Its in the documentation, just scroll down to "Reading the data".

Comment: @Tim I appreciate that you take the time to worry about the security aspect of it; trust me, I don't see this often :) but like Brent mentioned the request is signed, so any changes will cause the signature check to fail.

Comment: Thanks guys think I'm finally getting to understand this, guess I now need to figure out how to recalculate the signature in Python...

Comment: @Tim good luck with that, but I believe they use a portable hash function to calculate the signature so it _should_ be straightforward :)

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, it is not possible for the Facebook SDKs to explicitly create a new user. However, when you implement a 'Login with Facebook' button (see [here for JS](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/) and [here for PHP](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getLoginUrl/)), Facebook's OAuth dialog appears, which will prompt the user to log in (if they are not already) or to sign up with Facebook, thereby creating a new account, albeit not under your control.

Comment: But when the user has logged in and authorised my app, and I have the user details on the client side in JavaScript - can I use those details to automatically create an account on my website?

Comment: Yes, and you actually should. Then, after they logged in and their account is created (or the next time they log in through Facebook and you detect they already have an account), you use your site’s internal mechanism to log _your_ site’s corresponding user in automatically (your framework/CMS/whatever should provide a method to log in a user internally).